# I am getting error on installing phpmyadmin

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

While installing `phpMyAdmin` in `ubuntu` i am getting below error :

```
Setting up javascript-common (11) ...
dpkg: error processing package javascript-common (--configure):
 installed javascript-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 javascript-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: what version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: There's some problem with setting up the 'javascript-common' package. I suggest running `dpkg-reconfigure -plow javascript-common` to try to resolve the problem.